# Magento 2: Get image from the swatch id

Tags: magento2, swatches, color-swatches

I have attribute `color_swatch` which is visual swatch and it has some items with images.
In my code I can take this data:

```
[swatch_id] => 57
[color_swatch] => Red

[swatch_id] => 58
[color_swatch] => Blue

[swatch_id] => 59
[color_swatch] => Black
```

How can I get image of the swatch using this data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get swatch Image from this,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$swatch = $objectManager->create('Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data')->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$swatchId]);

$imageName= $swatch[$optionid]['value'];

if(!empty($imageName)){
$imagePath=$objectManager->create('Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media')->getSwatchMediaUrl().$imageName;
echo $imagePath;
}
```

You can find Image value from `eav_attribute_option_swatch` table. Where `value` is `Image path` and `type` `1` is uploaded image filer and `2` is color selected from color swatch.

---

***Note: I am against of direct loading object with `$objectManager`, for better impact you can inject it in your constructor. I have just given example how you can achieve it.***
`

Comment: If you're against using the object manager, why does your only suggested solution involve the object manager? :-)

Comment: @Keyur Shah do you have REST API link which i can get swatch value like above ? Thanks

Comment: how can I get swatch id?